# Error 403 because Google Cloud Vision client points to wrong project

Tags: google-cloud-vision, google-python-api

I'm trying to work through the Google Cloud Vision [Pyhon example](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/libraries) but I'm getting an authentication error.

This is not my only Google Cloud project, and my GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable is set to the path to my bigquery project. I thought I could override this by using this statement:

```
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient.from_service_account_json(key_path)
```

where `key_path` is the path of the json key file associated with my (Cloud Vision API-enabled) vision project. However, I'm getting the 403 error from this

```
response = client.label_detection(image=image)
```

Apparently, even though I specified the key file path for the ImageAnnotatorClient, it still looks at my bigquery project's credentials and spits the dummy because there is no vision API enabled for it.

Do I really have to change the environment variable every time I change the project?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Cloud Vision project ID does not propagate to the Python environment from either the Cloud Console or the credentials file. I fixed the reference using the Cloud Console:

```
gcloud config set project my_vision_project
```

The `label_detection` call works now.